# Apple style text input?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to get the apple-style text box, like this:
[image: Apple style search]

I want just a google search, but I want it in HTML, not code like this example. Any ideas?
If this uses javascript, that's OK.

Comment: Answer: **Yes there is.** Question: What have you tried? ( <- i know this should be a comment...) Hint: >! **Try CSS!**

Comment: Of course there is. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easily achieved using CSS. Here's a tutorial that should get you started:

http://www.bloggermint.com/2011/06/css3-search-box-inspired-by-apple-com/

Comment: my answer was better, but sadly converted to a comment :-(